# Are we going to allow Windows IoT (Internet of Things) questions?

Tags: discussion

With the official announcement of [Windows Internet of Things](https://dev.windows.com/en-US/iot) and it's release to the public today, I would like to get the communities opinion on whether we're going to allow [windowsiot](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windowsiot) tagged questions?

<sup>Note: You'll notice that there aren't any questions tagged `windowsiot` yet.  This is meant to get the opinion before they start coming in.</sup>

Comment: windows-iot, or internet-of-things read better than siot

Comment: @random I agree.  Was just basing it off the linked [SO tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-iot) from the [Windows IoT website](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/Community.htm).

Answer (score 2):

It looks more like it's for programming stuff, not for end-user consumption. I'd say for now it's off topic, *if it's asking a programming/programming issue question*. If it's for general use, and you can use regular computer applications on it, I'd let those skate by.

It might be better off on Electronics.SE, or Stack Overflow, or RaspberryPi.SE (for the RP2s). As well, there is currently an [Area51 Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80667/internet-of-things?referrer=Yqbb1G1P7quklORzjCokFw2) for Internet Of Things as a whole

Comment: I agree.  rPI2 will likely be the majority of the questions.  The rest of the IOT devices can be handled by their current handlers.  The fact they will now run "windows" shouldn't mean those questions need a new home..